# WSGI script displays as text, how can I make it execute?

Tags: python, flask, apache2, wsgi

I have followed the [instructions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/) on the Flask site for deploying using WSGI.

I know my apache2 server has wsgi enabled

```
$ sudo apache2 -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 ...
 wsgi_module (shared)
 Syntax OK
```

But when I go to the site address, it just shows the contents of the WSGI script.  I expected it to execute the script instead.

For example, the modwsgi wiki has several [test scripts](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation) that you can run to check your config, but when I modify my wsgi script to contain one of these test scripts and point my browser to the script, I just see the source code in my browser.

I see no errors in my apache2 log files.  What am I doing wrong?

My apache2 config looks like this

```
  1 <VirtualHost *>
  2     ServerName example.com
  3 
  4     WSGIDaemonProcess appname user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
  5     WSGIScriptAlias /appname /var/www/appname/appname.wsgi
  6 
  7     <Directory /var/www/appname>
  8         WSGIScriptReloading On
  9         WSGIProcessGroup appname
 10         WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
 11         Order deny,allow
 12         Allow from all
 13     </Directory>
 14 </VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/appname/appname.wsgi looks like this

```
import sys 

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = ''
    output += 'sys.version = %s\n' % repr(sys.version)
    output += 'sys.prefix = %s\n' % repr(sys.prefix)
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Comment: I fixed this by moving my apache2 configuration information from a separate /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myconfig file to the default configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/0000-default.  I'm not sure why this fixes it.  I know that the myconfig file was being parsed because I added a syntax error to the file and verified that apache choked when the daemon restarted.